# Perform a batch matrix - multiple weight matrices multiplications in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a batch of matrices *A* with size `torch.Size([batch_size, 9, 5])` and weight matrices *B* with size `torch.Size([3, 5, 6])`. In Keras, a simple `K.dot(A, B)` is able to handle the matrix multiplication to give an output with size `(batch_size, 9, 3, 6)`. Here, each row in *A* is multiplied to the 3 matrices in *B* to form a `(3x6)` matrix.

How do you perform a similar operation in torch. From the documentation, `torch.bmm` requires that *A* and *B* must have the same batch size, so I tried this:

```
B = B.unsqueeze(0).repeat((batch_size, 1, 1, 1))
B.size() # torch.Size([batch_size, 3, 5, 6])
torch.bmm(A,B) # gives an error
```

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: expected 3D tensor, got 4D

Well, the error is expected but how do I perform such an operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) to describe the operation you want as `bxy,iyk->bxik`. So, you can use `einsum` to calculate it.

`torch.einsum('bxy,iyk->bxik', (A, B))` will give you the answer you want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20879638)

Comment: Thanks a lot this was helpful!  `torch.einsum()` takes 2 argument, the second is the tuple (A,B)

Comment: @DerApe I reworded the answer to be authoritative.